# Active record and Joining with specific ID row

Tags: codeigniter, join

Here my problem :

- I have one controller called : events
- I have one view called : inscrits_liste
- I have one model called : inscrits_model

I have for my query 2 tables to work on :

Table 1 : inscrits
Table 2 : etats

And a third table called : events

In my table "etats"

I have 'etat_id' and 'etat_lib'

I would like to have the details from 1 "inscrit" with the lib of the 'etat'
for the event id specified.

**events.php**

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Events extends MY_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('event_model', 'event_m');             // Modele des évènements
        $this->load->model('inscrits_model', 'inscrits_m');             // Modele des inscrits
        $this->template->title('Gestion des évènements');
        $this->template->data('titre', 'EVENTS');
        $this->is_validated();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // Preparation du template

        $this->template->data('heading', 'Liste des evènements');
        $this->template->widgets('content', 'events_list');

        try
        {
            // On recupère la liste des events
            $this->template->data('evt', $this->event_m->get_all(array(), array('evenement_title ASC')));

            // On charge le template
            $this->template->load();
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getCode() . " => " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function inscrits($event_id)
    {
        // Preparation du template

        $this->template->data('heading', 'Liste des inscrits');
        $this->template->widgets('content', 'inscrits_liste');

        try
        {
            // On recupère la liste des inscrits
            $this->template->data('inscrits', $this->inscrits_m->inscrits_event($event_id));

            // On charge le template
            $this->template->load();
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getCode() . " => " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

**The model :**

```
<?php

class inscrits_model extends MY_Model
{

    protected $table = 'inscrits';
    protected $primary = 'inscrits_id';

    public function inscrits_event($event_id)
    {

        $this->db->select('inscrits_id,inscrits_pseudo,inscrits_nom,inscrits_prenom,inscrits_email,etat_lib');
        $this->db->from('inscrits');
        $this->db->join('etats', 'inscrits.inscrits_etat_id = etats.etat_id', 'inner');
        $this->db->where('inscrits_evenement_id', $event_id);
        $joint = $this->db->get();
        return $joint;
    }

}

/* End of file admin_model.php */
/* Location: ./application/models/admin_model.php */
```

The problem is to use the specific event_id to make the request on 1 inscrit for the current event.

I can't find the mechanism :s

I know the model do the query, the controller use the model to send datas to the view.
But in my case , in the model I would like to use a data given from a row in the view (the current event_id).

I'm lost!

Comment: please post error you receive :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your problem

```
    $joint = $this->db->get();
    return $joint;//this is not returning the results :)
```

you have to do:

```
 public function inscrits_event($event_id)
    {
$this->db->select('inscrits_id,inscrits_pseudo,inscrits_nom,inscrits_prenom,inscrits_email,etat_lib');
        $this->db->from('inscrits');
        $this->db->join('etats', 'inscrits.inscrits_etat_id = etats.etat_id', 'inner');
        $this->db->where('inscrits_evenement_id', $event_id);
        $joint = $this->db->get();
        return $joint->result();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry , but it wasnt my question/problem. Users already exists , events too. Actually the users subscribe to a event by the frontoffice of our website. We/i devellop the backoffice. In it i have a page with the differents events we have. When i click on one of the event i go on the page with the subscribed users. And by default the users get a state "not paid" with a column "inscrits_etat_id" linked with a table "etats". I just want to have the details of each users with the label of the state (located in "etats" table". so i make a inner join query, but it doesnt work. :)

Comment: @Kliklipse ok :) can you define "doesn't works" cause i can't understand where is your problem, can you post error you receive ? thanks

Comment: @Kliklipse ok gotcha, check my answer now, you have to use **return $joint->result()** for all records, **return $joint->row();** for a single record ;)

Comment: What a wonderfull answer :) You just resolved my problem. Now i can display a table with all my results , with a join query working :)
Thank you